# A problem on foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I want to get a picture like this.

[image]

The foreach command in the following code doesn't seem right. How should it be?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1/6} % radius of each semicircles
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{1/2*sqrt(3)} % height of each triangles

\foreach \i  in {0,1,2,3}
{\foreach \j  in {0,1,2}{
\begin{scope}[shift={(\i,\j)}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (60:1);
\coordinate (C) at (120:1);
\coordinate (K) at ($(A)!1/3!(B)$);
\coordinate (L) at ($(C)!1/3!(A)$);
\coordinate (M) at ($(B)!1/3!(C)$);
\draw (A)--(K) arc(-120:60:\r)--(B)--(M) arc(0:180:\r)--(C)--(L) arc(120:300:\r)--cycle;
\foreach \t in {A,B,C}{
\path[fill=white] (\t) circle (.1);
\draw[shift={(\t)}] (\t)--(30:.05)--(60:.1)--(90:.05) edge (\t)--(120:.1)--(150:.05) edge (\t)--(180:.1)--(210:.05) edge (\t)--(240:.1)--(270:.05) edge (\t)--(300:.1)--(330:.05) edge (\t)--(360:.1)--(30:.05);
}
\end{scope}
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good you and the cat :-) for the question and the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to relatively shift each other row and also choose the distance between the rows to be the height of the triangles, i.e. your macro `\a` (or `sin(60)`) instead of `1`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1/6} % radius of each semicircles
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{1/2*sqrt(3)} % height of each triangles

\foreach \i  in  {0,1,2,3}
{\foreach \j  in {0,1,2}
 {\begin{scope}[shift={({\i+0.25*pow(-1,\j)},{\j*\a})}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (60:1);
  \coordinate (C) at (120:1);
  \coordinate (K) at ($(A)!1/3!(B)$);
  \coordinate (L) at ($(C)!1/3!(A)$);
  \coordinate (M) at ($(B)!1/3!(C)$);
  \draw (A)--(K) arc(-120:60:\r)--(B)--(M) arc(0:180:\r)--(C)--(L) arc(120:300:\r)--cycle;
  \foreach \t in {A,B,C}{
   \path[fill=white] (\t) circle (.1);
   \draw[shift={(\t)}] (\t)--(30:.05)--(60:.1)--(90:.05) edge (\t)--(120:.1)--(150:.05) edge (\t)--(180:.1)--(210:.05) edge (\t)--(240:.1)--(270:.05) edge (\t)--(300:.1)--(330:.05) edge (\t)--(360:.1)--(30:.05);
   }
 \end{scope}}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to come closer to the first screen shot, consider removing the white circles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/flower/.style={code={
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) plot[samples at={0,1,...,11},variable=\t]
 (\t*30:{0.075+pow(-1,\t)*0.025}) -- cycle
 foreach \t in {0,1,2} {(\t*60+30:0.05) edge (\t*60+210:0.05)};
}}] 
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1/6} % radius of each semicircles
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{1/2*sqrt(3)} % height of each triangles

\foreach \i  in  {0,1,2,3}
{\foreach \j  in {0,1,2}
 {\begin{scope}[shift={({\i+0.25*pow(-1,\j)},{\j*\a})}]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (60:1);
  \coordinate (C) at (120:1);
  \coordinate (K) at ($(A)!1/3!(B)$);
  \coordinate (L) at ($(C)!1/3!(A)$);
  \coordinate (M) at ($(B)!1/3!(C)$);
  \draw (A)--(K) arc(-120:60:\r)--(B)--(M) 
    arc(0:180:\r)--(C)--(L) arc(120:300:\r)--cycle;
  \foreach \X in {A,B,C}{
   \path (\X) pic{flower};
   }
 \end{scope}}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I also put the smaller, flower-shaped objects in a `pic`.

Clipping such an image yields results that resemble your first screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1/6} % radius of each semicircles
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{1/2*sqrt(3)} % height of each triangles
\pgfmathsetmacro\b{3*\r/\a}% radius of the corner points 
\clip (-0.5,0.2) rectangle (5,5);
\foreach \j  in  {0,...,5}
{\ifodd\j
\edef\imax{5}
\else
\edef\imax{4}
\fi
\foreach \i  in {0,...,\imax}
 {\begin{scope}[shift={({\i+0.25*pow(-1,\j)},{\j*\a})}]
   \draw[very thick] (30:\b) -- ++ (180:2*\r) arc(00:180:\r) -- ++ (180:2*\r)
     -- ++(300:2*\r)  arc(120:300:\r) -- ++(300:2*\r)
    -- ++(60:2*\r)  arc(240:420:\r) -- cycle;%
  \foreach \X in {30,150,270}  
   {\draw[fill=white,shift={(\X:\b)}] (0,0) plot[samples at={0,1,...,11},variable=\t]
    (\t*30:{0.1+pow(-1,\t)*0.033}) -- cycle;
    \draw[shift={(\X:\b)}] foreach \Y in {0,1,2} {(\Y*60+30:0.066) --
    (\Y*60+210:0.066)};}
 \end{scope}}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code has been optimized a bit for speed. While it is possible to use patterns for this by superimposing two relatively shifted patterns, I did not succeed in constructing a version that looks good on most viewers.

Comment: Thank you for the tricks.That's very useful for me!